# C# ASP.NET Code Coverage - OpenCover No Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, opencover

I am using the following batch file to try and generate code coverage results:

```
@echo off

SET dotnet="C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe"  
SET opencover=.\packages\OpenCover.4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe  
SET reportgenerator=.\packages\ReportGenerator.2.5.8\tools\ReportGenerator.exe

SET targetargs="test .\test\IdentityServer.UnitTests\IdentityServer.UnitTests.csproj -f net461"  
SET filter="+[*]QuickstartIdentityServer* -[*.Tests]* -[xunit.*]* -[FluentValidation]*"  
SET coveragefile=Coverage.xml  
SET coveragedir=Coverage

REM Run code coverage analysis  
%opencover% -oldStyle -register:user -target:%dotnet% -output:%coveragefile% -targetargs:%targetargs% -filter:%filter% -skipautoprops -hideskipped:All

REM Generate the report  
%reportgenerator% -targetdir:%coveragedir% -reporttypes:Html;Badges -reports:%coveragefile% -verbosity:Error

REM Open the report  
start "report" "%coveragedir%\index.htm"
```

The test seem to run fine, but I get the following error message:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...

Total tests: 12. Passed: 12. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 4.0469 Seconds


Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
    output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    guide and the -register switch.
```

**Some more background on the projects:**

***Solution Structure:***

```
test project:SolutionDir\test\IdentityServer.UnitTests\IdentityServer.UnitTests.csproj

project being tested:
     path: SolutionDir\src\QuickstartIdentityServer\QuickstartIdentityServer.csproj
     target framework: net461
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What sort of PDB files are you generating?

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to [set `DebugType` to `full`](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/601#issuecomment-289405262) in your `.csproj` file:

```xml
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used OpenCover, but successfully used [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet)

You can see a full example [in this link: Cross platform code coverage arrives for .NET Core](http://tattoocoder.com/cross-platform-code-coverage-arrives-for-net-core/).

Basically you can add the package globally or in you project like below:

```
dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild
```

Than simple use the command:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true
```